# Authenticating user and also returning data from event

Tags: c#

So i have an issue where I am creating a spotifywebapi program that will query the users top tracks/artists of their lifetime, 6 months and month. This is using the SpotifyNet client found [here](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/)

I want the user to be able to load the page, authenticate and then return their data.. so current I have a web api method that would return the data but I am getting issues as I have to wait for authentication to happen before querying the api

```
    [HttpGet]
    //void until i get it working
    public void Get()
    {
        ImplicitGrantAuth auth = new ImplicitGrantAuth(
            "clientID",
            "http://localhost:4002",
            "http://localhost:4002",
            Scope.UserReadPrivate
        );

        auth.AuthReceived += async (sender, payload) =>
        {
            auth.Stop(); // `sender` is also the auth instance
            SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI()
            {
                TokenType = payload.TokenType,
                AccessToken = payload.AccessToken
            };
            Paging<FullTrack> shortTermTracks = api.GetUsersTopTracks(TimeRangeType.ShortTerm, 50, 0);
            Paging<FullTrack> mediumTermTracks = api.GetUsersTopTracks(TimeRangeType.MediumTerm, 50, 0);
            Paging<FullTrack> longTermTracks = api.GetUsersTopTracks(TimeRangeType.LongTerm, 50, 0);

        //NEED TO RETURN THIS DATA ABOVE BUT AUTHENTICATION HASNT OCCURED
        };
        auth.Start(); // Starts an internal HTTP Server
        auth.OpenBrowser();
    }
```

My thinking is potentially authenticating the user and went authentication happens.. redirect them with the the token and return the data but how would i pass the token to the redirect page?

Comment: Open an issue on the Github page because your follow there example and it does not work, so someone will have to set a wait method so it can make sure it's authenticated before it send the web requests

Comment: Seems to me like you need to implement an endpoint for auth that the spotify api will redirect to. Please see redirect_uri explanation here:  https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/auth/token_swap.html#token-swap-endpoint